# Windows Runtime: How to get the list of the user's preferred languages?

Tags: localization, internationalization, windows-8, windows-runtime

Some constructors of WinRT types accept an `IEnumerable<string>` of languages to try in resolving a choice of language. For example, there is [a `Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.CurrencyFormatter` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206886.aspx) that takes a list of languages to try in determining the choice of language of the currency formatter.

The only method I know of to access the user's language is to default-construct a [`Windows.Globalization.Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.language.aspx) object and access the [`Id` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.language.id.aspx). If the user has set a list of preferred languages, how is it possible to obtain the full list in the priority order that they specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this property is what you need: [`GlobalizationPreferences.Languages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences.languages). See the MSDN page on the [GlobalizationPreferences class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences) for more info.